# How to reload a component on routing back to it with no change in route parameter?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular9, angular-router

I have a unit component which loads with a router url "unit/:unitName". With respect to change in unit name, same component is rendered with different content.

I also a have a button in this component on clicking which, a routable modal which opens with URL "unit/:unitName/openPopup".

Now, On closing the modal, I am routing back to "unit/:unitName". What I want is my unit component to reload on closing of the popup, which I am not able to achieve.

I tried using routerReuseStategy.shouldReuseRoute = true/false at different place but it doesnt seem to work.
I want to use this reload functionality only for this component in my entire application. I do not want to modify the app routing as well.

What should I do to just reload the unit component on closing the modal?

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz demo?

Comment: Yes, will try to create it and post it here